# In Istio, service to service communication, does Kubernetes service required to setup?

Tags: kubernetes, istio

Hello I'm new to Istio and currently learning about Istio.

As per my understanding, Envoy proxy will resolve an IP address of destination instead of Kube DNS server. Envoy will send traffic directly to healthy pod based on information which received from control pane.

So... Does [Kubernetes service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) required to setup, if I'm using Istio?

Correct me if I'm wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/traffic-management/)

> In order to direct traffic within your mesh, Istio needs to know where
>   all your endpoints are, and which services they belong to. To populate
>   its own service registry, Istio connects to a service discovery
>   system. For example, if you’ve installed Istio on a Kubernetes
>   cluster, then Istio automatically detects the services and endpoints
>   in that cluster.

**So Kubernetes service is needed for istio to achieve service discovery i.e to know the POD IPs. But kubernetes service(L4) is not used for load balancing and routing traffic because L7 envoy proxy does that in istio.**

From the [docs](https://istio.io/docs/ops/deployment/requirements/).

> A pod must belong to at least one Kubernetes service even if the pod
>   does NOT expose any port. If a pod belongs to multiple Kubernetes
>   services, the services cannot use the same port number for different
>   protocols, for instance HTTP and TCP.